# Dynamically adding column to grid using Jquery Datatable and Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datatables

I want to add column dynamically based on the condition of the attribute that i am passing from the controller to view.I am using Jquerydatable for grid view and Spring as a framework.
I tried various to search solution but nothing seems to work.So can anyone suggest any solution to add a column dynamically only if the passed attribute satisfy the condition.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, if you come up with some code example.

Answer (score 0):

May be use javascript

```
    oColumns = [{ "mData": "id", "bVisible": 0 }]; // by default I set ID column
    columns = ["name", "email", "phoneNumber"]; // can initalize from server

    ${id}_columns.forEach(function(entry) {
    col = [{"mData": entry}];
    ${id}_oColumns = ${id}_oColumns.concat(col);
});

oTable = $('#$datatable').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "rest",
    "aoColumns": oColumns,
    });
```

Comment: Also you can include mData in your ajax response. Look at docs - http://datatables.net/usage/server-side